# Overlap between two vectors in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have such table:

```
    x   y   Z   w
u1  0   0   2   2
u2  1   0   1   2
u3  3   0   0   3
u4  2   2   5   9
u5  0   3   1   4
```

I want to calculate overlap between two rows. My Matlab code is :

```
for j = 1:4
    x = data(j,:);
    for i = j+1:5
        y = data(i,:);
        a = sum(max(x,y));
        b = sum(min(x,y));
        d = sqrt(b);
        over = d/a;
    end
end
```

but I want to show the overlap between rows in the result? For example, `overlap(1,2)` represents the overlap between the first and second rows. And so on. Result is:
    overlap(1,2)=?
    overlap(1,3)=?
    overlap(1,4)=?
    ...
    overlap(2,3)=?
    overlap(2,4)=?
    ...
What do I need to make this change to the code?
 I want like mtarix:

```
Overlap(1,1)    Overlap(1,2)    Overlap(1,3)    Overlap(1,4)    Overlap(1,5)
 Overlap(1,2)   Overlap(2,2)    Overlap(2,3)    Overlap(2,4)    Overlap(2,5)
 Overlap(1,3)   Overlap(2,3)    Overlap(3,3)    Overlap(3,4)    Overlap(3,5)
 Overlap(1,4)   Overlap(2,4)    Overlap(1,3)    Overlap(4,4)    Overlap(4,5)
 Overlap(1,5)   Overlap(2,5)    Overlap(3,5)    Overlap(4,5)    Overlap(5,5)
```

that instead of put overlap(x,y) values ​​obtained.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by “overlap”.

Comment: define a function that computes overlap and call it in a loop?

Comment: I update this. thank you.

Comment: What is the definition of overlap?

Comment: @abroekhof overlap is the formula that obtain  overlap between 2 category in library. in fact my matrix have 200 rows and 650 column. so I need to save the result. because when i use over = d/a; not save in another matrix that include 500 rows and 500 column. i need save result.

Comment: @sima412 isn't that what Dan answered below?  I've added something similar in my answer as well

Comment: @abroekhof yes it is. but this answer give me an error ("[hei,~] = size(data)") what this? sorry i don't know what is ~. and why give me error in matlab.

Comment: @abroekhof thank you very much. I get the result. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this, which returns a matrix of the number of overlapping elements in each combination of rows:

```
function [ overlap ] = overlap( mat )
[hei, ~] = size(mat);
overlap = zeros(hei);
for i = 1:hei
    for j = 1:hei
        overlap(i,j) = sum(mat(i,:) == mat(j,:));
    end 
end
end
```

EDIT:

Is this what you mean?

```
data = [0   0   2   2;
    1   0   1   2;
    3   0   0   3;
    2   2   5   9;
    0   3   1   4];
[hei,~] = size(data);
over = zeros(hei);
for j = 1:hei-1
    x = data(j,:);
    for i = j+1:hei
        y = data(i,:);
        a = sum(max(x,y));
        b = sum(min(x,y));
        d = sqrt(b);
        over(j,i) = d/a;
    end
end
over
```

Comment: give me error that function keyword use invalid here. what function do?

Comment: You put functions in files of the same name, and then call them from the command window.  Here, make an .m file called overlap.m.  Then in the command window you can write overlap(data)

Comment: @sima412 You can also just remove the line with `function` and the last `end` and it will work in normal code.  Replace `mat` with whatever the name of your matrix is.

Comment: I'm so sorry but i was a problem. i use this code: for j=1:6
x=mat(j,:);
for i=j+1:7
y=mat(i,:);
a=sum(max(x,y));
b=sum(min(x,y));
c=b-0.8;
d=sqrt(b*c);
overlap=d/a;
[hei,~] = size(mat);
overlap = zeros(hei);
for k = 1:hei
    for h = 1:hei
        overlap(k,h) = sum(mat(k,:) == mat(h,:));
    end 
end
end
end       . but give me wrong result that one number. my code is this and i remove function and end. is it true?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why EitanT took his answer away, it seemed correct to me. So I'll leave this edited version here for now until:

```
data= [0   0   2   2
       1   0   1   2
       3   0   0   3
       2   2   5   9
       0   3   1   4]


for j = 1:4
    x = data(j,:);
    for i = j+1:5
        y = data(i,:);
        a = sum(max(x,y));
        b = sum(min(x,y));
        d = sqrt(b);
        over(i-1,j) = d/a;
    end
end 

over =

   0.34641   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
   0.17678   0.24744   0.00000   0.00000
   0.11111   0.11111   0.11769   0.00000
   0.19245   0.19245   0.15746   0.13925
```

All you need to do is save each overlap calculation to a different element of your `over` matrix